# How to specify -style PRETTY in com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode

Tags: gwt, firebug

GWT 2.0.4 seems to have removed support for the -style argument:

> Unknown argument: -style PRETTY

How can I get DevMode to generate readable Javascript output so that I can use Firebug to usefully profile it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevMode doesn't compile your Java code to JavaScript (that's what DevMode is for: execute your Java code as Java so you can bind a Java debugger) so there's no need for a "-style".

Previous versions of GWT had a "compile and run" button in the HostedMode, which took into account the "-style" given on the command line, but this is no longer the case so there's no need for a "-style" parameter.
You'll find it on Compiler though, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [Google Plugin for Eclipse](http://code.google.com/eclipse/)? It has a [setting](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/gwt_compile.html) for that.

Comment: No, I'm using Intellij IDEA. It has a similar configuration, but I believe that for both IDEs this option only applies to deployed apps, not to DevMode.

Comment: I don't think DevMode obfuscates Javascript. The obfuscation only happens during compile time.